# custom format in JSON for DateTimeField with mongorecord

Tags: json, scala, mongodb, datetime, lift

im using lift-mongodb-record 2.4.
All of my MongoRecord models include the following [DateTimeField](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/record/field/DateTimeField.html) field, eg:

```
object created_at extends DateTimeField(this)
```

when i call asJSON on this model, it'll parse the date into a string e.g.

```
Mon, 16 Jul 2012 21:26:58 GMT
```

I would prefer other formats (eg. ISO 8601, depends on the acutal use-case)

*how and where would I set up a custom format?*

thanks

Comment: You'll have to parse this back in I think :/ sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding *asJValue*  and *setFromJValue* should do the trick since the default implementation uses the so called internet date, like in the following:

```
val statusDate = new DateTimeField(this){

  val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
  override def asJValue = {
    asJString(v => sdf.format(v.getTime))
  }

  override def setFromJValue(jvalue: JValue) = setFromJString(jvalue) {
    v =>tryo {
        sdf.parse(v)
      }.map(d => {
      val cal = Calendar.getInstance
      cal.setTime(d)
      cal
    })
  }
}
```